# CORS issue Angular + PHP REST API

Tags: php, angular, cors

l'm having issues with CORS but l have added them in the server side, which is my php register api, my login works perfectly without any cors issues but the register one keeps on rejecting, refer to the code below.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//include CORS headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers,    Authorization, X-Requested-With");

//including files
include_once("../config/db.php");

include_once("../classes/Users.php");

//objects
$db = new Database();

$connection = $db->connect();

$user_obj = new Users($connection);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    if(!empty($data->name) && !empty($data->email) && !empty($data->password)){

        $user_obj->name = $data->name;
        $user_obj->email = $data->email;
        $user_obj->password = password_hash($data->password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $email_data = $user_obj->check_email();

        if(!empty($email_data)){
            //some data we have - insert should not go
            http_response_code(500);
            echo json_encode(array(
                "status" => 0,
                "error" => "User already exists, try another email address"
            ));
        }
        else{
            if($user_obj->create_user()){
                http_response_code(200);
                echo json_encode(array(
                    'status' => 1,
                    "message" => "User has been created"
                ));
            }
        }
    }
    else{
       http_response_code(500);
         echo json_encode(array(
            'status' => 0,
            "error" => "All data needed"
         ));
    }
}
else{
    http_response_code(503);
    echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => 0,
        "error" => "Access Denied"
    ));
}

?>
```

the below is my Angular service that call the api

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class JarwisService {

  private baseUrl = 'https://domain.co.za/Backend/endpoints';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  signup(data: any){
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/signup.php`, data);
  }

  login(data: any){
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/login.php`, data)
  }
}
```

Can someone assist me what l might be missing, the api does register a user l test using postman(l know postman doesn't use CORS)

the error l face is below

[image]

Comment: Why are you giving the client permission to send a `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` request header? It's a response header. It should never appear on the request. Your client-side code doesn't appear to be sending `Authorization` or `X-Requested-With` headers either, so why grant permission for them?

Comment: thanks for the help as well combined with @Quentin suggestion both help on the solution

Answer (score 0):

The preflight request is an OPTIONS request.

You are sending `http_response_code(503);` in response to everything that isn't a POST request.

You need a 200 OK for the preflight.